# Setting up boost property_tree for a custom path type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I need to use boost::property_tree in my program. Right now I'm having hard time trying to figure out how to use it with a custom path type. The path type I want to have is `Framework::CommonClientServer::InterfacePathChain_t`

which is typedef'ed like this:

```
typedef std::vector<InterfaceID_t> InterfacePathChain_t;
typedef int InterfaceID_t;
```

So basically the path type should be `std::vector<int>`.

For example:

```
     0
    / \
   1   2
  /   / \
 3   4   5
```

These nodes will have the following paths:

```
0: {0}
1: {0, 0}
2: {0, 1}
3: {0, 0, 0}
4: {0, 1, 0}
5: {0, 1, 1}
```

I've defined the `path_of` struct in the following way:

```
namespace boost { namespace property_tree {
template<> class path_of<Framework::CommonClientServer::InterfacePathChain_t>
{
public:

    typedef Framework::CommonClientServer::InterfacePathChain_t key_type;

    struct type 
    {
        key_type path;  
    public:
        type(key_type pathVal)
        {
            path = pathVal;
        }

        std::string dump() const    
        {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            if (path.size() > 0)
            {
                key_type::const_iterator it = path.begin();
                oss << *it;
                ++it;
                while(it != path.end())
                {
                    oss << '.' << *it;
                    ++it;
                };
            }
            return oss.str();
        }

        bool empty() const  
        {
            return path.size() == 0;
        }

        key_type reduce()   
        {
            key_type res;
            res.push_back(*path.begin());
            path.erase(path.begin());
            return res;
        }

        bool single() const 
        {
            return path.size() == 1;
        }
    };
};
}}
```

After that I tried adding 2 nodes with different paths and IDs to the tree, but it doesn't seem to work. Actually, the first node is being added with the id I set (the path is {0}). But the second node (path is {0, 0} so it's supposed to be a child for node1) doesn't seem to be added. When I try to iterate through the tree, this happens:

```
MetaStorageTree tree;
Framework::CommonClientServer::InterfacePathChain_t path;
path.push_back(0);
MetaStorageTreeNode* node = new MetaStorageTreeNode(1);
tree.put(path, node);
Framework::CommonClientServer::InterfacePathChain_t path1;
path1.push_back(0);
path1.push_back(0);
MetaStorageTreeNode* node1 = new MetaStorageTreeNode(2);
tree.put(path1, node);
for (auto it : tree)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < it.first.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << it.first[i];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        if (it.second.empty()) //this returns true so node1 does not have a child
        {
            std::cout << "empty" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

I believe I did something wrong with typedef'ing all the things in boost::property_tree I needed, but couldn't find any sufficient information on the topic, since most use of property_tree is dedicated to JSON parsing so standard std::string path type is used.

Comment: "Most of property_tree is dedicated to JSON parsing" is non-sense. In fact, it's JSON support is abysmal, and it has two more serialization backends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a logical misconception is at the root of this. You don't actually specialize a tree to use another path type.

You specialize it for another `key_type` (in this case, you want it to be `InterfaceID_t`). The path type for use in queries is only implicitly derived and never stored.

The path type can therefore not "be" `InterfacePathChain_t`, for it must be `path_of<key_type>::type`, and must adhere to the concept you implemented above. Instead, though, you *can* make the `path_type` be implicitly convertible from `InterfacePathChain_t`.

Implementing all the required changes, we arrive at the following test program:

```
using MetaStorageTree = boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Framework::CommonClientServer::InterfaceID_t, std::string>;

void dump_tree_for_debug(MetaStorageTree const&);

int main() {
    MetaStorageTree tree;

    using Framework::CommonClientServer::InterfacePathChain_t;
    tree.put(InterfacePathChain_t{0}, "0");
    tree.put(InterfacePathChain_t{0, 0}, "1");
    tree.put(InterfacePathChain_t{0, 1}, "2");
    tree.put(InterfacePathChain_t{0, 0, 0}, "3");
    tree.put(InterfacePathChain_t{0, 1, 0}, "4");
    tree.put(InterfacePathChain_t{0, 1, 1}, "5");

    dump_tree_for_debug(tree);
}
```

- I elected to implement `path_of<int>::type` using a `deque<int>` which is is both more natural to the task, and underlines the fact that it does **NOT** need to be identical to `InterfacePathChain_t`.
- I added output to XML; however, the serialization backends of PropertyTree *assume* that `path_type::value_type` be a valid stream character type. Since this is not the case for your chosen tree specialization, I have added a helper function to `convert_weird_tree` to standard `ptree`.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90d2ee05f5ac5133)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

namespace Framework { namespace CommonClientServer {
    using InterfaceID_t = int;
    using InterfacePathChain_t = std::vector<InterfaceID_t>;
} }

namespace boost { namespace property_tree {
    template<> struct path_of<Framework::CommonClientServer::InterfaceID_t>
    {
        typedef Framework::CommonClientServer::InterfaceID_t key_type;
        typedef std::deque<key_type> path_type;

        struct type 
        {
            path_type path;  
        public:
            // this allows us to easily convert paths to string in convert_weird_tree... (DEBUG)
            explicit type(Framework::CommonClientServer::InterfaceID_t id) : path { id } {}

            type(Framework::CommonClientServer::InterfacePathChain_t chain) : path(chain.begin(), chain.end()) {}
            type(path_type pathVal) : path(std::move(pathVal)) {}

            std::string dump() const    {
                std::string r;
                for (auto id : path)
                    r += std::to_string(id) + ".";
                if (r.size())
                    r.resize(r.size()-1);
                return r;
            }

            bool empty() const  { return path.empty(); }
            bool single() const { return path.size() == 1; }

            key_type reduce()   {
                key_type res = path.front();
                path.pop_front();
                return res;
            }
        };
    };
} }

// Test code
using MetaStorageTree = boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Framework::CommonClientServer::InterfaceID_t, std::string>;

void dump_tree_for_debug(MetaStorageTree const&);

int main() {
    MetaStorageTree tree;

    using Framework::CommonClientServer::InterfacePathChain_t;
    tree.put(InterfacePathChain_t{0}, "0");
    tree.put(InterfacePathChain_t{0, 0}, "1");
    tree.put(InterfacePathChain_t{0, 1}, "2");
    tree.put(InterfacePathChain_t{0, 0, 0}, "3");
    tree.put(InterfacePathChain_t{0, 1, 0}, "4");
    tree.put(InterfacePathChain_t{0, 1, 1}, "5");

    dump_tree_for_debug(tree);
}

// FOR DEBUG/DEMO PURPOSES:
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename WeirdTree, typename Path = typename WeirdTree::path_type>
boost::property_tree::ptree convert_weird_tree(WeirdTree const& weird) {
    boost::property_tree::ptree normal;

    if (auto v = weird.template get_value_optional<std::string>()) {
        normal.put_value(*v);
    }

    for (auto& element : weird) {
        normal.add_child(Path{element.first}.dump(), convert_weird_tree(element.second));
    }

    return normal;
}

void dump_tree_for_debug(MetaStorageTree const& tree) {
    write_xml(std::cout, convert_weird_tree(tree), boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 2));
}
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<0>
  0
  <0>
    1
    <0>3</0>
  </0>
  <1>
    2
    <0>4</0>
    <1>5</1>
  </1>
</0>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. This did clarify some things to me, but not completely yet.

Comment: Well. Let us know what you are missing. Perhaps just post another targeted question about it.

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry, forgot to accept your answer at that moment - was too excited. Unfortunately, I've found out that there is no way of getting the parent node of a child node in boost::property_tree (see this question [Getting boost property_tree parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366768/getting-boost-property-tree-parent-node), which was answered by you as well). That was essential, so we had to quit using boost::property_tree and configure our own.